# How to make and unattended installation of OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

I have a script that creates a virtualhost in the server. Would it be possible to feed the database credentials to the `october:install` command, rather than type them in manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `october:env` command then setting the ENV variables to the relevant configuration values (see the .env file the is created). Once configured, simply run `october:up` to migrate the database.

Comment: I wound up writing out a file called `.env_temp` with the variables and values necessary. Then I run `october:env` so that it string replaces all the vars in the files in /config. Finally I delete original env `rm .env` and rename the temp file `mv .env_temp .env`

Comment: I'm also interested in this but couldn't quite follow your steps. Could you explain a bit more?